What are the Chebyshev sets for the taxicab metric?
A set of points $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is called a Chebyshev set if the metric projection w.r.t $S$ is single-valued. That is, for every point $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, there is a unique point $y\in S$ that minimizes the distance to $x$.
WHen the distance is measured by the Euclidean metric ($\ell_2$). it is known that $S$ is a Chebyshev set if and only if it is closed and convex.
MY QUESTION: suppose the distance is measured by the taxicab metric ($\ell_1$). What are the Chebyshev sets in this case?

Every closed and convex subset is a Proximinal set, i.e. for every point $x$ the metric projection $P(x)$ is non empty but it need not be Chebyshev. This is because the $\ell_1$ norm is not rotund.

Surprisingly to me, it appears that $S$ need not be convex!
Let $\| \cdot \|$ be any norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and consider the induced metric $d(x, y) = \| x - y \|$. I have the following geometric picture in mind: to calculate the projection wrt $d$ from a point $x$ onto a set $S$, we consider the balls $B_r(x)$ of various radii around $x$. These are scaled copies of the unit ball $B$ and we can imagine the ball scaling up bigger and bigger until the first time it touches $S$.
For example if $n = 2$ and we take the $\ell^1$ norm then the unit ball is the familiar square rotated $45^{\circ}$ and we are just seeing what happens when we scale this square until it touches $S$. Now consider the following choice of $S$: the "bent half-plane" given by all points to the left of the rays
$$L_1 = \{ (x, 2x) : x \ge 0 \}$$
and
$$L_2 = \{ (x, -2x) : x \ge 0 \}.$$
Then I claim that $S$ is Chebyshev with respect to the $\ell^1$ norm (but is not convex). The projection from a point $p$ is obtained, as above, by scaling up the rotated square until it touches $S$, which always happens at the point obtained by moving directly left from $p$ (as in, parallel to the $x$-axis) until we touch $S$. In the $\ell^2$ norm $S$ is not Chebyshev because, for example, the point $(1, 0)$ does not have a unique projection: when we start with a circle around that point and scale up it touches $S$ at two points. But the western corner of the $\ell^1$ unit sphere has a sharp enough angle that this can't happen here.
Generally it seems that $S$ can be "bent" in various directions depending on "how sharp the corners are" of the unit ball of the norm $\| \cdot \|$ in those directions. Hopefully you can see geometrically how this should work although writing down precisely what this means seems tricky.
I think it should still be true that a sufficient, although not necessary, condition is that $S$ is closed, convex, and furthermore does not contain a "hyperplane segment" parallel to any hyperplane segment of the unit sphere of $\| \cdot \|$. (For example, if we bend the lines $L_1, L_2$ above until they have slope $\pm 1$, matching the slopes of the sides of the rotated square, then the projection of $(1, 0)$ will no longer be unique.)
